# Java - Asterisk, what does it mean

Tags: java, syntax

I'm looking through the Alexa SDK.  In the documentation here, they have the following:

[`directivesServices.enqueue(SendDirectiveRequest.\*builder\*().build());`](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/wiki/Alexa-Service-Clients)

What on earth does that asterisk do?  I have never seen one in my life, and I'm curious as to what I've been missing out on.

Comment: It looks like incorrect formatting - someone attempting to use markup within a code snippet, while that is not supported. It's not valid Java. Have you tried to use the code snippet without the asterisks? Did it work?

Comment: Is it possible they weren't intentional? Maybe they were meant to be asterisks used in markdown to emphasize the code.

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you posted an issue on that repo.

Comment: My interpretation would be that this is pseudo-code for "invoke any Builder-methods you need", but it is hard to tell without an actual API reference.

Comment: seriously? someone messes up some mark-up and this got 5 upvotes? :) SO can be a surprising place sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisks (`*`) aren't part of Java's syntax.

It's a botched attempt in that page to emphasize the call to [`SendDirectiveRequest.builder`](http://ask-sdk-java-javadocs.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/com/amazon/ask/model/services/directive/SendDirectiveRequest.html#builder--). That line of code should read:

```
directivesServices.enqueue(SendDirectiveRequest.builder().build());
```